# Sails.js/Waterline: is it possible to perform a "silent" update (without affecting updatedAt field)?

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

So I want to update my model without changing `updatedAt` field (not by default). Does Waterline have such a feature at this moment?

Comment: Nope. They have not suport yet

Answer (score 0):

Short story: this is not yet possible.

As you can see from [this code](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/blob/v0.12.2/lib/waterline/query/dql/update.js#L196) in waterline 0.12.2, the field `updatedAt` is automatically updated if `autoUpdatedAt` is set to true.

This leaves you with two possible solutions:

- You can temporarily turn off `autoUpdatedAt` before your update
- You can use a manual query. [See `.query` for more details](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/query)